# How can I make an iterate driver for a dolist style macro?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

Suppose I have dolist style macro such as this:

```
(defmacro do-factorials (var n &body body) 
  (let ((i (gensym)))
    `(let ((,var 1))
       (dotimes (,i ,n)
     (setf ,var (* ,var (1+ ,i)))
     ,@body)))))
```

I would like to make a driver for the [iterate](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) library, which would allow me to do something like this:

```
(iter (for x in-factorials 10)
      (for y in '(a b c d e))
      (format t "~a ~a~%" x y))
```

However, as far as I can tell, the iter macro can only be extended with clauses that expand into other iterate clauses, whereas for this, I need to be able to wrap other code inside of a do-factorials. Is there anyway to do this in a reliable manner?

The implementation for in-hashtable and in-package work similar to how my in-factorials would work, but they are implemented using internal functions and macros, and I would prefer not to use symbols that aren't exported or documented.

For this simple case it would be easy to rewrite it with iterate, but, in general, that isn't always doable. For instance, the do-whatever macro could be from a third-party library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm haven't really used cl:iterate, but based on the documentation and example in [7.2 Writing Drivers](http://common-lisp.net/~loliveira/tmp/iterate-manual/html_node/Writing-Drivers.html#Writing-Drivers), I came up with this:

```
(defmacro-driver (FOR var IN-FACTORIALS n)
  "All the factorials from 1! to n!."
  (let ((end (gensym))
        (fact (gensym))
        (index (gensym))
        (kwd (if generate 'generate 'for)))
    `(progn
       (with ,end = ,n)
       (with ,fact = 1)
       (with ,index = 0)
       (,kwd ,var next (progn (incf ,index)
                              (if (> ,index ,end) (terminate))
                              (setf ,fact (* ,fact ,index)))))))
```

After evaluating that, I can run the code that you showed:

```
CL-USER> (iter (for x in-factorials 10)
               (for y in '(a b c d e))
               (format t "~a ~a~%" x y))
1 A
2 B
6 C
24 D
120 E
NIL
```

According to the documentation, you still might want to handle the `&sequence` stuff, but (not being a cl:iterate user), I'm not sure whether it's necessary or not for something that's not a sequence:

> We are still missing one thing: the &sequence keywords. We can get
>   them easily enough, by writing
>
> ```
> (defmacro-driver (FOR var IN-WHOLE-VECTOR v &sequence)
>   …)
> ```
>
> We can now refer to parameters from, to, by, etc. which contain either
>   the values for the corresponding keyword, or nil if the keyword was
>   not supplied. Implementing the right code for these keywords is
>   cumbersome but not difficult; it is left as an exercise. But before
>   you begin, see defclause-sequence below for an easier way.

I'm not sure whether or not this falls into what you mean when you say:

> *For this simple case it would be easy to rewrite it with iterate, but,
>   in general, that isn't always doable. For instance, the do-whatever
>   macro could be from a third-party library.*

In general, a macro `do-xxx` doesn't necessarily expose its iteration technique, which means that you're not going to be able to coöpt its implementation into iterate.  I don't really see a way around that, so I think that you'll probably have to rewrite some of it in terms of cl:iterate.  However, I didn't use anything that wasn't described in the documentation (and I'm completely new to cl:iterate), so I think you're safe on:

> *The implementation for in-hashtable and in-package work similar to how
>   my in-factorials would work, but they are implemented using internal
>   functions and macros, and I would prefer not to use symbols that
>   aren't exported or documented.*

Comment: What I gave was just an example. Perhaps a better example would be a third-party hashset library, where the only mechanism to loop over it is with `do-hashset`. It doesn't appear like there is any way to create a driver for said hashset in iterate.  One possible solution would be to combine the do-hashet with cl-cont, but then I would need to wrap the body in a macro, which I can't figure out how to do in a driver definition.

Comment: @Thayne Exactly.  Unless the existing iteration macro exposes its implementation, or you can somehow "pause" in between iterations, you'll either need to do the iteration ahead of time and collect the elements, or reimplement the iteration.